# java nio fails to write to file, old school file works. What's wrong?`

Tags: java, file, nio

The following MWE shows my understanding of how to write a file using nio.  It fails on opening the file however.  To demonstrate that there is nothing wrong with the directory, an old-school file is written in the same project, same directory.  What is wrong with the nio code?

The error: Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: test.dat.  Note that the option is set to CREATE which is supposed to either write to an existing file or create a new one!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;

public class FastWritenio {
    public static void writeUsingPrintWriter() throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
        pw.print("testing");
        pw.close();
    }
    public static void writeUsingnio(int numTrials, int bufferSize, int putsPer) throws IOException {
        String filename = "test.dat";
        java.nio.file.Path filePath = Paths.get(filename);
        WritableByteChannel channel = Files.newByteChannel(filePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
        for (int t = 0; t < numTrials; ++t) {
            for (int i = 0; i < putsPer; i ++) {
                buf.putInt(i);
            }
            buf.flip(); // stop modifying buffer so it can be written to disk
            channel.write(buf);  // Write your buffer's data.
        }
        channel.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        writeUsingPrintWriter();
        writeUsingnio(16, 8*1024, 1024);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception for failing to open?

Comment: You beat me to it! See the edit

Comment: Maybe typo? `text.txt != test.dat`

Comment: Paths.get(filename) returns the absolute path of the file, whereas in PrintWriter you're writing to the current directory. Is there something wrong the path Paths.get returns?

Comment: How do I create a file in the current directory?

Comment: @codebrane No it doesn't. It returns a `Path` valued `test.dat`, and even if it didn't it wouldn't explain this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Quted from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html):

> Both `newByteChannel` methods enable you to specify a list of OpenOption options. The same open options used by the `newOutputStream` methods are supported, in addition to one more option: `READ` is required because the `SeekableByteChannel` supports both reading and writing.
>
> Specifying `READ` opens the channel for reading. Specifying `WRITE` or `APPEND` opens the channel for writing. If none of these options is specified, the channel is opened for reading.

Your `OpenOptions` are insufficient. Setting `WritableByteChannel channel = Files.newByteChannel(filePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);` in your example creates the file on Windows, but ends up in a `BufferOverflow`.

Comment: I am going to put the amended code in the question, because although it works, it is ludicrously slow, so hopefully something is very wrong.

Comment: If the Answer was a solution to you inital question feel free to accept it ;)

Comment: @Dov You need `buf.compact()` after the write to solve the `BufferOverflowException`.

Comment: buf.flip() by itself does not work either. The file opens but then as EJP points out the buffer overflows.